# Getting my (do)gi white again

Tags: judo, equipment, gi, dogi

I have read this M.A. question: [What are the ways to get sweat stains out of a Gi?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/17/what-are-the-ways-to-get-sweat-stains-out-of-a-gi/27#27)
My gi is at least two years old (probably a lot older). It is an Adidas J800 (do)gi.

It is 30% polyester (800 g/m² polycotton) and cannot be washed warmer then 30 degreed Celsius. I wash it after every practice.

I would like it to be more white. It does not have stains, it is just a bit off-white, yellow. I dislike it so much that I even consider to buy a new one. But on the other hand it seems a waste to me because the gi's fiber is still ok. It is just the overall color. Especially in the collar. It just looks unhygienic to me.

I have tried washing it with [Vanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanish_%28brand%29#UK_product) and some detergent which is especially for white clothes.

A new judo gi will be over € 150,- so I would like to take a good look at my washing habbits, because this is not the first gi that became 'yellow'. Below are pictures of my 'should-be-white' gi with the washing-description.

My other gi which is 100% cotton has the same look.

ps. my sleeves seem to became shorter too, so maybe I just washed it too much and I have to just buy a new one?

**edit** I have found this online source http://www.budogi.co.uk/judo-gi-care-instructions/
and I do not iron my gi and just hang it to dry. I use [liquid detergent](http://www.robijndoetdewas.nl/producten/robijn-stralend-wit-klein-krachtig) (sorry for dutch link). Can Fabric conditioner be the cause of this yellow color?

[image: j800 label]
[image: collar gi]
[image: washing description]

Comment: €150 seems really high for a Judo gi.  Most of the ones I get are around £30/40...

Comment: size 185 and 800gr/m²? it is € 162,- http://www.nihonsport.nl/pakken/judopakken/adidas-judopak-j800-wit.html Mizuno is even more expensive http://www.nihonsport.nl/pakken/judopakken.html?brands=4

Comment: [Nine circles](http://www.ninecircles.co.uk/Clothing/Aikido_Gi/Aikidogi_-_Deluxe_750g_Sashiko_Ori.aspx) has some (okay, they are Aikido gi...) for €50ish...  *Note that I am only affiliated with Nine Circles as a customer.*

Answer (score 4):

To clarify on the use of bleach, as long as it is non-chlorine based (like borax or OxiClean) you should be fine to use it. Chlorine bleach will yellow your non 100% cotton clothes but color safe or oxygen based bleaches should be fine.

Personally, I use baking soda (somewhere between 1/4 and 1/2 a cup depending upon your washer/load size/etc.) to keep my workout whites bright and it works well as a preventative measure (especially if you have hard water); you might need something stronger to remove the existing discoloration though, like the methods mentioned in Dave's answer.  Some vinegar (1/2c to 2c again depending upon your washer/load size/etc.) could also help a little, though its more for preserving fabrics and softening them.

I would also like to add that how you dry your (do)gi can also affect its color.  Air drying in the sun for a little while can help bleach it back to white. Plus it is much better for the fabric than using a dryer!

Answer (score 1):

You may have hard water that is yellowing them. I haven't had much success with reversing the process, but there are some palliative approaches like [lemon juice, borax, and bluing agents](http://www.mamaslaundrytalk.com/have-your-white-clothes-turned-yellow/).

Comment: 4 really nice suggestions, thanks, will take a look at them and will update this question with the results!

Answer (score 0):

Adding some bleach to the wash might make a difference. If it was 100% cotton, I would recommend it but 30% polyester *might* do something strange...

Comment: I also have emblems on my shoulders which might be bleached then? http://www.nihonsport.nl/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/j/7/j730_493d41dd50b28.jpg I don't mind an experiment by the way. I have probably have to buy a new gi anyway.

Comment: Yes, the emblems will be bleached as well unless you remove them first.  You *could* do some clever bleaching in a bucket but that will leave you with a yellowish halo around the emblems.

Comment: Bleach is generally contraindicated for washing grappling gi, since it weakens the fabric.